# How to retrieve Global picklist using metadata api?

Tags: metadata-api, global-picklist

I am trying to implement a retrieval of global picklist values in apex using metadata API but I am not able to understand how to do that. Anyone having any idea. I was looking at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalpicklist.htm but was not able to understand.
I am trying to send the UI(lightning component) the picklist values of country and state which are global picklists.

Answer (score 2):

When retrieving Standard Picklists you need to use `StandardValueSet` in your xml package just like this:

`<type>
  <member>CaseOrigin</member>
  <name>StandardValueSet</name>
 </type>`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm

This is a list of standard picklists names:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm
If you are trying to retrieve custom picklist values just retrieve them as custom fields like this:

`<types>
      <members>ObjectAPIName.PicklistAPIName</members>
      <name>CustomField</name>
  </types>`

If you want to retrieve global picklists you need to use GlobalValue Set.
If there is a field in your object that is referencing a global picklist with values then you need to retrieve the field along with the global picklist.

`<types>
      <members>ObjectAPIName.PicklistAPIName</members>
      <name>CustomField</name>
  </types>
  <types>
      <members>GlobalPicklistAPIName</members>
      <name>GlobalValueSet</name>
  </types>`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalvalueset.htm

I hope this helps!
If you still have issues, please post a sample of your package.xml file.